# Can't pass state value from child to parent component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a state inside of child component that I want to use in parent component. This is how my components set:

Child:

```
export default class Child extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      value: "123",
    };
  }
updateValue(data){
    this.props.updateValue(data);
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.updateValue(this.state.value);
}
}
```

Parent:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super(props)
    this.state = {  
        newValue: ""
    };
  }

updateState (data) {
        this.setState(newValue: data);
    }
  render() {
return(
        <Child updateValue={this.updateState.bind(this)}/>
)
}
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work and gives me an error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And what does error says ?

Comment: `this.setState(newValue: data);` is not a valid object - should be `this.setState({newValue: data});`

Comment: It's telling you exactly what's wrong. Literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `this.setState` takes an argument. You have passed a key:value pair that isn't stored in a data structure.

```
this.setState(newValue: data);
```

should be

```
this.setState({newValue: data});
```